# Trying to export field accessibility metadata for all object fields

Tags: metadata, fields, data-export, dbamp

I'm trying to find a way to export the field accessibility metadata for all object fields. It appears like I should be able to do this with my linked objects within my SQL server database using dbamp to link to the raw Salesforce object tables. I've found the list of Profiles but I can't find the link to the raw field accessibility metadata.

Anyone tried this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Force.com IDE to access Metadata. Here is the URL, where you can read about "How to use Force.com IDE"

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/ide_getting_started.htm

Once configured, you should check Profile data and there you will find all details about field accessibility.